# VIM stopped accepting a keyboard command

Tags: bash, vim

For some reason as of 3 days ago my VIM stopped accepting `Ctrl-x` from me. I have this combo mapped to Copy to X clipboard. It worked perfectly before 3 days ago. I have not changed my `.vimrc` file at all in that time nor upgraded any app/console.

```
vmap <c-x> "+yi
```

This worked perfectly up till now for almost a year since I created this mapping.

This is of course in Visual Mode. If in Edit Mode I hit the same Key Combo then the `^X` mode comes up. So I know the terminal is letting the `Ctrl` through.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come to find out it wasn't anything to do with my `.vimrc` or my terminal app. Sometime in the past I had removed `vim-gnome` for some reason. Without realizing it this broke vim's ability to communicate with Xclipboard.

After re-installing `vim-gnome` it now works as expected:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Found here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard